# CocoaPods project depend on a local static C library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have locally built C library (`.h` and `.a` files) that I want to include in a Swift-based CocoaPods pod. How do I configure the podspec to depend on the `.a` files and the `module.map`? With a normal non-CocoaPods Xcode project, I simply drag in the directory that contains `include` and `lib` and then add a `module.map`. With CocoaPods I can't do this because `pod install` will overwrite the Xcode project file. `s.library` won't work because the the static library isn't hosted anywhere. I tried `s.vendored_libraries` but `module.map` still remains unknown to Xcode, the end result being that `import foo` from my Swift files is an error.

Edit: I tried using `preserve_paths`, `vendored_libraries` and `xcconfig` as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609714). The issue is still how to import the module from Swift.

Edit 2: I also tried using `module_map` to point to my `module.map` file as [documented here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#module_map), but sadly CocoaPods 1.1.1 crashes (`[!] Oh no, an error occurred.`).

Comment: Have you tried adding module to Import Paths under Swift Compiler – Search Paths in your project settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. In my case I'm depending the libtiff C library which is prebuilt for iOS (x86 and arm) using https://github.com/ashtons/libtiff-ios.

I used a subspec as [outline here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609714). Here's the podspec subspec snippet, assuming the static library lives at `libtiff` off the root of the pod module.

```
s.subspec 'libtiff' do |libtiff|
  libtiff.source_files = 'libtiff/include/*.h'
  libtiff.public_header_files = 'libtiff/include/*.h'
  libtiff.preserve_paths = 'libtiff/include/*.h'
  libtiff.vendored_libraries = 'libtiff/lib/libjpeg.a', 'libtiff/lib/libpng.a', 'libtiff/lib/libtiff.a', 'libtiff/lib/libtiffxx.a'
  libtiff.xcconfig = { 'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => "${PODS_ROOT}/#{s.name}/libtiff/include/**" }
  # you can't specify "libz" here, must specify "z", see https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3232
  libtiff.library = 'z'
end
```

Comment: I had same requirement and done everything, but still getting some error *Library not found for -l{libraryname}* . Any inputs to fix it?